# how to use jquery in zend_form in zend studio?

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, zend-form

how to use jquery in zend form? I am using zend studio 9 as editor and i'll include jquery library but i don't know how to use it to validate zend form. i found tutorial but they include zendx_jquery but there's no this type of library in zend studio.

Comment: i know this is silly question but i can't get answer. so i posted here. there's no need to vote down!! if you know then answer it otherwise leave it

Comment: The thing is: jQuery and Zend_Form has nothing to do with your IDE. You should post what you've tried so far too. Are you already familirized with ZF and jQuery? Just make a XHR request to the controller you want... that's all. No need for ZendX_JQuery. I've not downvoted, but I should have ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use jQuery the same way you would in any other application.  If you are interested in ZendX, you will have to download the full Zend framework package from http://framework.zend.com/download/latest.  Then search for the ZendX folder and add it to your project library.  Personnally, I don't use it but you could start there.  If you simply want to use jQuery for your form validation, I strongly recommend the following video: http://www.zendcasts.com/ajaxify-your-zend_form-validation-with-jquery/2010/04/ .  This is what I use for any client-side validation in my forms.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $form is your Zend_Form. Set an onSubmit attribute like so:

```
$form->setAttrib('onclick', 'yourJavascriptValidationFunction()');
```

or, alternatively, give your form an id or classname (also with `setAttrib()` ), and bind the validation function in JavaScript directly on the element.